# ¿Cómo hacer la comparación entre dos objetos de una clase?

Tags: java

```
public class LicensePlate {
private String letters;
private int numbers;
private String city;

public LicensePlate(String letters, int numbers, String city) {
    this.letters = letters;
    this.numbers = numbers;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getLetters() {
    return letters;
}

public int getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de comparación quieres hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar una comparación de igualdad entre objetos se utiliza el método `equals()` que devuelve un valor booleano, este método lo poseen todas las clases ya que lo heredan implicitamente de la clase `Object`.

```
boolean respuesta = obj1.equals(obj2);
```

Si lo que necesitas es realizar una comparación en cuanto si es menor o mayor uno o varios de los atributos de la clase puedes implementar la interface `Comparable` y sobrescribir su método `compareTo()`.

**Nota:** El método `equals()` lo puedes sobrescribir y realizar una comparación personalizada.

Answer (score 0):

debes implementar la interfaz comparable en la clase donde tienes el objeto , desarrollar el metodo compare to que solo son unos if o un return y desarrollar el equals y hashcode que genera java.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/145669)

Comment: es la respuesta correcta a la pregunta.no requiere clarificacion. solo leer.saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
Tienes que implementar la interfaz Comparable.
```

Supongamos que las quieres comparar por atributo numbers tendrías que hacer esto en el método compareTo();

```
@Override public int compareTo(Object o) { 
  LicensePlate licensePlate = (LicensePlate) o; 
  if (this.getNumbers() == licencePlate.getNumbers()) return 0; 
  else if (this.getNumbers() > licensePlate.getNumbers()) return 1; 
  else return -1; 
}
```

Devuelve 0 si son iguales, devuelve 1 si el objeto recibido es menor, y devuelve -1 si el objetivo recibido es mayor.

Tu clase quedaría así:

```
public class LicensePlate implements Comparable {
private String letters;
private int numbers;
private String city;

public LicensePlate(String letters, int numbers, String city) {
    this.letters = letters;
    this.numbers = numbers;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getLetters() {
    return letters;
}

public int getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
```

@Override public int compareTo(Object o) {

```
  LicensePlate licensePlate = (LicensePlate) o; 
  if (this.getNumbers() == licencePlate.getNumbers()) return 0; 
  else if (this.getNumbers() > licensePlate.getNumbers()) return -1; 
  else return 1; 
}
    }
```